# Custom JSpinner

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I have created the following class that extends `JSpinner` to iterate over dd/mm/yyy values.

```
public class DateSpinner extends JSpinner{

    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

    public DateSpinner(){
    super();

    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    Date now = calendar.getTime();

    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -2);
    Date startDate = calendar.getTime();

    calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 100);
    Date endDate = calendar.getTime();

    SpinnerDateModel dateModel = new SpinnerDateModel
        ( now , startDate , endDate , Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH );

    setModel(dateModel);

    JFormattedTextField tf =
        ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor)getEditor()).getTextField();
    DefaultFormatterFactory factory =
        (DefaultFormatterFactory)tf.getFormatterFactory();
    DateFormatter formatter = (DateFormatter)factory.getDefaultFormatter();

    // Change the date format to only show the hours
    formatter.setFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    }




}
```

My problem is when I set its value using

```
    Date today = new Date();
    spinner.setValue(today);
```

I get the date including the time and day of the week. If I touch the spinner it formats it according to the format I set. How can I initially get the format I want to be shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use built-in editors, such as following

```
spinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, "dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, as a side note - whenever you work with calendars, dates and times I would consider using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: And, `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime` classes are available if you are working with Java8 APIs.